# Ffmpeg can't open m3u8 link

Tags: ffmpeg

Ffmpeg can't play `https://live.webcamromania.ro/WR051/wrcam_051/playlist.m3u8`. It gives an Input/Output error. With other links it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

`[tls @ 0x7fb19f405bc0] IO Error: -9806 http://live.webcamromania.ro/WR051/wrcam_051/playlist.m3u8: Input/output error`

This output means, that the TLS (https) is not accepted. This could be because the TLS of the webserver is invalid (seems here not the case) or because FFmpeg was compiled with and old / outdated SSL library.

Depending on your operating system, check for the latest updates of the SSL library and re-compile FFmpeg or check that you're using the latest version of FFmpeg.

For future questions show the full command you're using and also the full output. This helps us to give you more detailed information and better help.

Comment: I don't know how to compile ffmpeg with ssl support. Also, I'm running windows 10 and I downloaded Ffmpeg from the oficial website.

Comment: The FFmpeg wiki has some compilation tutorials: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide